# Highlight and Unhighlight Searched Text in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsattributedstring

I want to highlight and unhighlight the searched text in `UITableView`.

For Highlighting the searched text, i have tried below code in `CellForRow` and Highlighting searched text works fine.

```
let range = (self.modelClass.users[indexPath.row].name as NSString).range(of: self.searchBar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive)
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.modelClass.users[indexPath.row].name)
attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: Colors.highlightedColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: cell.lblName.font], range: range)
cell.lblName.attributedText = attributedString
```

**EDIT 1**

```
if searchBar.text != "" {
    let range = (self.modelClass.users[indexPath.row].name as NSString).range(of: self.searchBar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive)
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.modelClass.users[indexPath.row].name)
    attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: Colors.highlightedColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: cell.lblName.font], range: range)
    cell.lblName.attributedText = attributedString
}
else {
    cell.lblName.text = self.modelClass.users[indexPath.row].name
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Actually me 1st code is working fine. First i assign normal text to `lblName.text` and then after again i set `attributedText` to `lblName.attributedText`. When i comment the normal text assign, it works fine.

But when i clear searched data and load my default array but the highlighted color wasn't clear in `lblName` `UILabel`.

Please guide me how can i unhighlight the `UILabel` text?

Answer (score 1):

in cellForRowAt, You also need to pass an else condition for the default label view.

```
if self.searchBar.text != "" {    
let range = (self.modelClass.users[indexPath.row].name as NSString).range(of: 
self.searchBar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive)
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: 
self.modelClass.users[indexPath.row].name)
attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: 
Colors.highlightedColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: cell.lblName.font], range: range)
cell.lblName.attributedText = attributedString 
} 
else { 
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.modelClass.users[indexPath.row].name as NSString)
attributeString.removeAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
cell.lblName.attributedText = attributeString    
}
```

Reload TableView when searchBar text changes.

Comment: please add complete code of cellForRowAt. Also add a breakpoint and check whether the else condition is executed or not.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Actually me 1st code is working fine. Only the issue is that Before set `attributedText`, i set `lblName.text` value.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension for UILabel to manage this

```
extension UILabel {

        func stringWithSearchBarString(_ string: String) {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text ?? "")
            if string.count == 0 {
                attributedText = attributedString
                return
            }
            let dotRanges: [NSRange]
            do {
                let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: string.lowercased(), options: [])
                dotRanges = regex.matches(in: string.lowercased(), options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.count)).map {$0.range}
            } catch {
                dotRanges = []
            }
            let rangeColor = WXColors.mainAppColor.color
            for dotRange in dotRanges {
                attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: rangeColor, range: dotRange)
            }
            attributedText = attributedString
        }
```

}

USAGE:

`cell.textLabel.stringWithSearchBarString(searcher.text)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Actually me 1st code is working fine. Only the issue is that Before set `attributedText`, i set `lblName.text` value.